# How to send a notification to a specific peer using Peer.js

Tags: node.js, express, peerjs

I'm trying to send a specific notification for each peer connected to my server.

I'm trying to send the notification in the same way the peer client works, but its methods are not supported. How can I send a notification from the server to a specific peer?

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = new PeerServer({port: 9000, path: '/myapp'});
var connected = [];
server.on('connection', function (id) {
  var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only add id if it's not in the list yet
  if (idx === -1) {connected.push(id);}
});
server.on('disconnect', function (id) {
  var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only attempt to remove id if it's in the list
  if (idx !== -1) {connected.splice(idx, 1);}
});

var app = express();

var turn = {
  type: 1,
  selection: "NINGUNA",
  timestamp: new Date().getTime()
};

app.get('/connected-people', function (req, res) {
  var list = connected;

  for(var i = 0; i < connected.length; i++){    
    var conn = server.connect(connected[i]);
    console.log(connected[i]);
    conn.on('open', function(){
      conn.send(turn);
    });
  }

  return res.json(connected);
});
```

But this way, the notification doesn't get sent to the peers. 
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have enough rep for a comment but looking at what you are trying to do I would think you could just use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for the direct server to peer communication.

Looking at the docs for [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) shows that

> To broker connections, PeerJS connects to a PeerServer. Note that no peer-to-peer data goes through the server; The server acts only as a connection broker.

It doesn't appear to be setup to handle direct communication with peers, however socket.io can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
peerServer.on('connection', client => {

        client.socket.on('message', data => {
                //message to filter
                console.log('from client:', data);
        });
});
```

Comment: How do you send a message from the client to the peer server and vice versa?

Comment: According to the docs of peerjs-client side a "connection' event occurs when a connection is established with the remote peer. Not with the peer server. https://peerjs.com/docs.html#api

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. This is what I have tested and works. You need to use socket.io, or similar, this is a simple way to do the required signaling.
You can emit to a especific peer or to the whole room using broadcast or simply socket.to(room).emit, it will send the message to all the members of a room except the originator.
Client side:

```
// Set up event listener for a peer server data connection established event
peer.on("open", (id) => {
    console.log('*** "open" event received from userId: ' + id + ', occurs when connection to peer server is established');
    socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
    console.log('*** "join-room" emit for ROOM_ID: ' + ROOM_ID + ', and userId: ' + id);
});
```

When you create a peer instance, for instance:

```
// Create a new instance of the class Peer
const peer = new Peer({
    host: '/',
    path: '/peerjs',
    debug: 2,
    port: 3030,
});
```

it connects to the peer server at the host/port/protocol/etc. that you indicate and it returns an 'open' event to indicate that the connection is established with the server. It returns the id of the client. or peer.id named userId above.

You do send messages back to the server from the client using the code above:

```
socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
        console.log('*** "join-room" emit for ROOM_ID: ' + ROOM_ID + ', and userId: ' + id);
```

Now to have the server respond to the client's "join-room" event. You do something like this from the server side:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('***Server received "connection" event on socket.io interface');
    socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
        console.log('*** "join-room" event received from client: ' + userId + ' in roomId: ' + roomId);
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId);
        console.log('*** "user-connected" event broadcasted to roomId: ' + roomId + ' for userId: ' + userId + ' from server');
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId);
            console.log('*** "disconnect" event broadcasted to roomId: ' + roomId + ' for userId: ' + userId + ' from server');
        });
    });
    socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
    });
});
```

Now, remember to set up listeners for the events that you send on your clients, so that they react and take some action when the event comes, for instance to act on a user disconnect event I send a message to all the peers about the event, and they all listen by incorporating this handler in their code:

```
// Set up event listener for user-disconnected event, returns userId
socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
    if (peers[userId]) { // if it exists close connection
        peers[userId].close();
        console.log('*** "user-disconnected" event received from userId: ' + userId);
    }
});
```

The limit in how to communicate is your imagination, you can set up timed functions with setTimout that send the event 'messages' and then react at the client, or viceverse from any client.

A complete working example with data and voice/video media between n clients and data communication with the nodejs server and peerjs server using the socket.io package you can check this [example](https://github.com/spine001/working_peer_js_WebRTC_Nodejs_example).

Answer (score 0):

peer.socket._socket is an instance of WebSocket so you can listen to the "message" event on it and do your stuff.

Client code:

```
peer.on('open', id => {
    peer.socket._socket.addEventListener('message', message => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Server code:

```
peerServer.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.send({ hello: 'world' });
});
```